# hyperledger fabric - stuck at creating cli

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I was building the network at fabric level. Following this tutorial http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html
I have made changes in the following files and added 2 more peers in organisation1 only.

1. configtx.yaml
2. crypto-config.yaml
3. docker-compose-cli.yaml
4. docker-compose-couch.yaml
5. docker-compose-e2e.yaml
6. docker-compose-e2e-template.yaml
7. docker-compose-base.yaml

When im firing ./byfn.sh -m up command

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t0uY.png)

Its getting stuck at this step. Its not even showing any error.

Im trying to add 2 more peers in first organisation. Is this the correct way? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the logs for the containers to see if there is a particular error?  You are starting quite a few containers does your machine have the resources to run them?  As mentioned in Rocket Chat, the scripts/script.sh is expecting to work with only 4 peers I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also happened to me ,

1.`sudo docker stop $(docker ps --all -q ) |  docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`,be attention just rm the docker related to the fabric node

2. reboot your computer and restart your docker service 
   `sudo service docker start` or `systemctl start docker` command